# Iterate through nested collection and form org structure with Parent

Tags: c#, linq, recursion, linq-to-entities

I have a batch of users defined with that model.

I need to iterate inside Manager nesting while manager is not null and create Departments entities with parents relation. I have an example of code what I already have, so I post it here.

What I already have:

```
   public class AdUserModel  
        {
            public string UserName { get; set; }
            
            public AdUserModel Manager { get; set; }
    
        }
```

```
...

            List<UserDepartment> userDepartmentsToAdd = new List<UserDepartment>();
            List<Department> newDeps = new List<Department>();

            RecurseDepartments(adUser);

            var userDepartment = new UserDepartment
                    {
                        User = user,
                        PositionName = adUser.PositionName,
                        Department = newDeps.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == adUser.DepartmentName),
                        IsHeadUser = user.SubordinateUsers?.Any() ?? false
                    };

                    userDepartmentsToAdd.Add(userDepartment);

             void RecurseDepartments(AdUserModel model)
                    {
                  
                   var department = new Department();
                   var existDep = newDeps.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == 
                                                model.DepartmentName);

                if (existDep == null)
                {
                    department.Name = model.DepartmentName;
                }
                
                    if (model.Manager is not null)
                    {
                        if (newDeps.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == model.Manager.DepartmentName) == null)
                        {
                            var parentDepartment = new Department
                            {
                                Name = model.Manager.DepartmentName
                            };
                            department.ParentDepartment = existDep ?? department;
                            if (existDep == null)
                            {
                                newDeps.Add(department);
                            }
                            newDeps.Add(parentDepartment);
                        }
                        
                        if (model.Manager.DepartmentName != model.DepartmentName)
                        {
                            RecurseDepartments(model.Manager);
                        }
                    }

            }
```

Thanks for any help in advance, being stuck here for some reason.

Comment: Why not just add parent property to existing class AdUserModel so you can move up easily.

Comment: What kind of property do you mean? Can you show example, please @jdweng?

Comment: Department parent { get ;set; }

Comment: How can I use it then? I have only string ParentDepartment {get ;set;}

Comment: The parent should be a Department.  Where the root Department parent is null and when you add a new department you add the parent to the new Department.  A string doesn't help when you need to iterate through the tree.  You always can get the name of the parent through the parent Department.

Comment: On the layer of AdUserModel I can only have string name of parent department.

Comment: Put in the Department (or <UserDepartment) class, not the AdUserModel class.